# Swiper Slider with Centered Auto and Continuous Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiper to created an auto centered swiper with slides of various widths like below:

https://swiperjs.com/demos/140-centered-auto/core.html

That all works great. However I also want it to loop so that it is a continuous loop. Right now it somewhat loops, however it just gets to the end and then quickly animates back to slide 1. However, I would like for it to be a continuous loop so it doesn't quickly animate back to slide 1 when it reaches the last slide. I would like for it to just keep going... similar to the swiper shown below:

https://swiperjs.com/demos/200-infinite-loop/core.html

Is that not possible when slides are set to centeredSlides: true and slidesPerView: "auto"?